# Oledeb command builder, got it wrong

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

```
Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Mokmeuh.accdb")
        con.Open()
        dAdapter.UpdateCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Articles SET Nom = @p1, Prix = @p2, Quantité = @p3 WHERE ((Nom = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND Prix IS NULL) OR (Prix = @p2)) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND Quantité IS NULL) OR (Quantité = @p3)))", con)
        dAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarChar, 4, "Nom")
        dAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Single, 4, "Prix")
        dAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.Integer, 4, "Quantité")

        dAdapter.Update(dSet.Tables("Articles_table"))
    End Using
```

This would be my command with my parameters but I throw me an error so I get it wrong but I don't know how to fix it, the error is telling you : The Update affected 0 where it should have affected one

So, where do i get this wrong

Edit : database type

[image]

Comment: I would strip back your update statement to try and find there error in steps. Also, a good idea would be to go to Access and build the SQL in there, there's a Query editor where you can write out this statement and if it show's no results there, you no its not the code that's at fault. You need to try to take it step by step to resolve issues like this.

Comment: Please do not update the question content with text like *some moderator please delete this* etc. I have rolled back that update. If you still wish, you can probably **flag** for moderator attention but I don't think the request will be accepted because this question already has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we dont know your data well enough to help you. But, here is how you can help yourself. Turn that UPDATE into a SELECT and see what results you get.  Your WHERE sql seems strange but again, without your data, it may just look strange when it is perfectly logical.

```
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE ((Nom = @p1) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND Prix IS NULL) OR (Prix = @p2)) AND ((@p2 = 1 AND Quantité IS NULL) OR (Quantité = @p3)))
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of data what do you need more ?, the table ?

Comment: Did you attempt the SELECT idea mentioned above?  We dont need the data if you do this.

Comment: Give me a second I was in class, do you want me to run it throught vb or with MS access

Comment: You have to do VB, since it has your parameters. Also, for future referece, if you think there are records it should be working on, example data should include at least all fields outlined in the code (for 1-2 records) as well as the value for each parameter.

Comment: While I test that I,ve updated the table name and everythings take a look if you want

Comment: it's seems Ic an't get it working if I don,t define the parameter and if I defined them it still throw exception